# Alternative to sockets library for GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sockets

Is there an alternative to Python's standard lib module `sockets` that runs on Google AppEngine? Sockets are disabled there due to the sandbox.

I have looked at the other similar questions, but in them the answer was that sockets weren't implemented, not the question. One of them mentions a link to a form for becoming a trusted tester who has access to these features, but I haven't heard from Google yet :/

I'm thinking Twisted as it supports whole lot of protocols but I don't know much about sockets and how they work, so I'm not sure.

Comment: You can only make HTTP and HTTPS requests from App Engine. Nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can only make HTTP and HTTPS requests on App Engine. Nothing else.

The closest thing you can get on App Engine is the [Channels](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview) API, which may do what you need.

urllib3 isn't even related. It does HTTP and HTTPS, not sockets.

Comment: The purpose of my app was just to log some channels on IRC. Will the Channles API help there? Considering that once the page has been delivered the JS code is free to do w/e it wants, is there some way of opening a socket there?

Comment: @YatharthROCK: Nothing but a Channel or a WebSocket. YOu can look at the App Engine XMPP API though.

Comment: I mean, can I open a socket or w/e would be enough using JS to join and watch an IRC channel?

Comment: @YatharthROCK: I don't understand what your asking.

Comment: I meant, can I create a socket through the JS? AppEngine does not have any restrictions there, right?

Comment: @yatharth: nope, sorry js doesn't let you do this either.

Answer (score 2):

Good news! Google recently released a sockets API for app engine, documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/

It is still in a preview release (as of Mar. 2014) and it comes with its own host of limitations, but it should be able to handle many situations.